# Expanding the output to the top 5 email addresses (from the top 1) in Python script

Tags: python-3.x

my last homework assignment is writing a script that finds the 5 most common email addresses in a text file (linked on hastebin below). I've found a way to find the single most common email address, but how can I expand this output to the top 5? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
while True:
try:
    filename = input("Enter a file name: ")
    fhand = open(filename, 'r')
    email_addresses = {}

    for line in fhand:
        if line.startswith("From "):
            email = line.split()[1]
            email_addresses[email] = email_addresses.get(email, 0) + 1

    max_address = None
    max_emails = 0
    for k in email_addresses:
        if email_addresses[k] > max_emails:
            max_address = k
            max_emails = email_addresses[k]

    print(max_address, max_emails)
    print(email_addresses, email)

    ans = input('Do you want to try another file?: (y/n): ')
    ans = ans.lower()
    if ans == 'y':
        continue
    if ans == 'n':
        print('Thanks for playing!')
        break
    else:
        continue

except:
    print('File name',fname,'does not exist.')
    continue
```

And the text file: https://hastebin.com/egixurubak.makefile

Comment: Use [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) e.g. `Counter(email_addresses).most_common(5)`

Answer (score 0):

A quick idea:
Find the single most common email address in `email_addresses`, remove it from the dict, store it in a list, find the next single most common email address....